# Why does the BADSIG/"Untrusted sources" error recur forever?

Tags: software-center

On at least a dozen occasions, I've spent 2-3 hours figuring out how to get Ubuntu 11.10-12.10 to either update or acquire software from software center, or both. I want to fix whatever is causing the BADSIG problem *once and for all*; I've wasted so much time trying to get this to work well enough that I can rely on it, but the same problem comes back after a couple weeks of normal updates and software center usage.

Don't refer me to a standard posted solution on the web---whatever it is, I've used it more times than you have. The question *isn't* whether I can get it to work right this afternoon. I can. The question is what is causing the problem to recur regularly across 3 releases.

Notice: I use this computer 4-5 hours per week and I do little on it. PDFs, Latex, FireFox, Mendeley, and that's it. I don't constantly install new software, and I don't fiddle with things unnecessarily.

Comment: Could you describe what exactly you tried so far? What packages (from which repositories) do you want to install?

Comment: In the past I have issued the typical clean/update terminal commands, I've disabled all inessential PPAs, I've edited my sources list, and a whole lot of other more complicated (usually ineffective) 3 to 10-step fixes posted here and elsewhere. After trying a half dozen different things, it'll eventually work (and not with the same solution, consistently).

Just learned of Y PPA, so I'm good now.

Answer (score 1):

I do not regard this problem as solved, and I don't understand why Ubuntu works so well on my machine at home, and so consistently poorly (in this particular respect only) on my machine at my office. However, Y PPA has made it easy to live with the problem, as it will fix the BADSIG issue automatically, in just a few seconds:

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/10/y-ppa-manager-0092-released-with-new.html